# Export cxGrid to excel not showing file type in SaveDialog window

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, tcxgrid

This isn't a massive problem but I would like to know if I am doing something wrong.

I have a cxgrid on a delphi form and at a click of a button I can export it to Excel.

Code:

```
TfrmMain.ExcelButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with SaveDialog do
  begin
    Filter := '*.xls';
    if Execute
      then ExportGridToExcel(SaveDialog.FileName,Grid,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,'xls');
  end;
end;
```

When the save dialog box appears, the **Save As Type** is blank and not showing the file extension.

Is there something else I need to do?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: In the IDE, have you set the Filter property of your TSaveDialog using the Object Inspector?  If not, that's probably the step you've missed..

Comment: This has nothing to do with cxGrid and everything to do with the save dialog control. Look there for answers. Did you read the docs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SaveDialog.Filter := 'Excel Files (*.xls)|*.xls'
```